# Express js - Use routes in separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to setup a node project and I want to put a file `routes.js` in `routes/routes.js` and controllers files in `controllers/` directory.

So, for example I have the `UserController` like this:

```
var index = () =>
{
  console.log("User Index");
};
var getUser = (id) => {
  console.log("User by id " + id);
};

module.exports =
{
  index,
  getUser
}
```

And in `routes.js` I have this:

```
    var express = require('express');
var routes = express.Router();
var users = require('../controllers/usersController');


routes.route('/')
  .get(users.index);

routes.route('/user/:userId')
  .get(users.getUser);


module.exports=
{
  routes
};
```

And in `index.js` I'm setup in this way:

```
    let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let routes = require('./routes/routes');

app.set("views", './views');
app.set("view engine", 'jade');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/', routes.index);
// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(9001);
```

When I try to run the server I have this error:

```
.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
  throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
  ^
  TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
```

What is the problem how can I configure setup this in this way?

Thank you

Comment: did you copy paste this code?

Comment: In `routes.js` you never export anything called `index`, and thus in the line `app.use('/', routes.index)` inside of `index.js`,  `routes.index` is undefined. You do however export something called `routes` (as in `routes.routes`), so maybe that's what you meant to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `routes.js` replace:

```
module.exports=
{
  routes
};
```

to

```
module.exports = routes;
```

in `index.js`

`app.use('/', routes.index);` to `app.use('/', routes);`

should works...

Answer (score 4):

Your userController will be like this.

```
 module.exports = {
        index: (req, res) => {
            console.log("User Index");
        },
        getUser: (req, res) => {
            console.log("User by id " + req.params.id);
        }
    }
```

Your routes file will be like this

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = express.Router();
var users = require('../controllers/usersController');

routes.get('/', user.index);
routes.get('/user/:userId', user.getUser);

module.exports = routes;
```

Your index file will be like this

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let routes = require('./routes/routes');

app.set("views", './views');
app.set("view engine", 'jade');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(9001);
```